# make nstextfield single line

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, line, multiline, nstextfield

how to make NSTextField really single line?

I created a text field programmatically. when the return key is pressed, all text is selected. but I can still paste multiple lines of text. And when I press Arrow-right or Arrow down, it scroll to the next line.

There aren't these issues if I use IB and set the "use single line mode", but I couldn't find the right method to set it programmatically.

Comment: IB does a lot of magic default setting, you can sometimes examine the xib to see what key value pairs are set

Comment: @GradyPlayer Yeah it does, the problem is  I want to set it programmatically.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried telling [the field's cell](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/cell) to [set whether it uses single-line mode](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCell/setUsesSingleLineMode%3a)?

```
[myTextField.cell setUsesSingleLineMode:YES];
```

Comment: Much simpler than the solution I found, which is attaching a nsformatter.

Comment: Now if only line wrapping were disabled by default, and the characters shifted to the left as you typed... 

Comment: Oh sweet, using `textField.cell.scrollable = YES` does what I want. 

Answer (score 14):

This works for me when programmatically creating controls:

```
[myTextField.cell setWraps:NO];
[myTextField.cell setScrollable:YES];
```

Keep in mind that direct access to NSControl's cell has been discouraged since OS X 10.10 introduction:

> Gradual deprecation of NSCell
>
> Mac OS X 10.10 takes another step towards the eventual deprecation of
>   cells. Direct access to the cell of a control is discouraged, and
>   methods which allow it will be formally deprecated in a subsequent
>   release. A variety of cell-level APIs have been promoted to various
>   Control subclasses in order to provide cell-free access to important
>   functionality. NSLevelIndicator, NSTextField, NSSearchField, NSSlider,
>   and NSPathControl all have new properties for this purpose. Cell-based
>   NSTableViews are now deprecated, and view-based NSTableViews should be
>   used instead. Matrix-based NSBrowsers are also deprecated in favor of
>   the item-based interface.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/

Comment: Do you know if there a way to set the text field to be scrollable without accessing its cell? Invoking `setUsesSingleLineMode:` on the text field (as opposed to the cell) doesn't make it scrollable.

Comment: Control + Enter make textfield two line again.