# How do I create a single line text input field for OSX?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am trying to programmatically create a simple text input field for OSX that is only one line, has no scroll bar and automatically scrolls right and left when the user types and cursors.  I have tried using a NSTextField, but it always seems to be multi line.  I found the following link which seems to address the issue but it does not work for me.

[make nstextfield single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659185/make-nstextfield-single-line)

I create the NSTextField, add it to my view and set 'setUsesSingleLineMode' of it's NSCell to 'YES', but the text field still wraps text when I reach the end of the field rather that scrolling.

I have also tried using NSTextView with and without a surrounding NSScrollView, but, in this case I cannot get it to scroll either horizontally or vertically.

If someone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from Eclipse SWT, should be easy to translate from Java to Objective C:

```
NSTextField widget = new NSTextField ().alloc ();
widget.init ();
NSCell cell = widget.cell();
cell.setWraps(false);
cell.setScrollable(true);
```